# Responsve React Native font size

Tags: react-native, fonts, responsive

How to manage font size in different size of screens, When assigning font size for the 
small-screen devices i.e (5 and 5.5) then it displays bigger in large-screen device i.e(6 and 6.5) and it happens vice-versa in Android,

I have already used but it didn't work
[react-native-responsive-fontsize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-responsive-fontsize)

Comment: Do you want to fix the font size?

Comment: yes, I assign fix the size of the font size for all screen size of the device